# How to enable keep_alive setting for armeria grpc server?

Tags: armeria

As a part of serverBuilder of GRPC there are couple of options where armeria server builder takes. One is **channelOption** and **childChannelOption** which takes in **ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE** and a boolean. Even though I set these parameters i get an message saying
**Unknown channel option 'SO_KEEPALIVE' for channel '[id:xxxxx]'**
Can some one suggest how it can done as a part of armeria serverbuilder?

Answer (score 0):

It's done like the following:

```java
Server server =
    Server.builder()
          .childChannelOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
          ...
          .build();
```

I confirmed that `Unknown channel option 'SO_KEEPALIVE'` error does not occur.